# Fill Grid By Taking Value From Angular Js scope variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, gridview

I have read data from server side and stored in scope variable and now I have to display it on grid
please refer the code I have written

**script.js**

```
$scope.collection_report = []; // just initialize an array to store data coming from server
Collection_report.get({}, function (response) { // success

  $scope.collection_report = response.data; // store result to variable

  }, function (error) { // ajax loading error
      Data.errorMsg(); // display error notification
  });
```

**grid.html**

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="account_report in $collection_report">
     <td data-title="id">{{$index+1}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I am getting the server side data successfully, because it shows in console.but I cant load it in to grid.
please help me.

Comment: `$collection_report` should be simply `collection_report`

Comment: And make sure when you update $scope.collection_report, its in a digest cycle, meaning you might have todo: `$timeout(function(){ $scope.collection_report = response.data;});`

Comment: @user814628 why do I use that ?

Comment: If you're updating scope variables outside of angular, like in events or ajax calls, you have to tell angular that you have changed one of its scope variables. One way to achieve this is to use angular $timeout, which kicks off a digest cycle, which will pick up the new changes and update accordingly.